# Type mismatch error in VBA when using mmult loops

Tags: vba, mismatch

I am creating a code to calculate the portfolio standard deviation of equal-weighted portfolio of stocks from 1 to 40 stocks. The matrix formula for portfolio variance is just w^T*sigma*w where w = column vector weights of each stock, sigma = the variance covariance matrix and w^T is the transpose of the column vector

I have created the variance covariance matrix, a row vector of weights, and I am running a loop to calculate the portfolio variance. The code for the loop is below, but I am getting the error that "Unable to get the MMult property of the WorksheetFunction class"

Could someone please shed some light?

```
Sub StandardDeviation()

    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer


    Worksheets("Trial 1").Activate
    Range("B80").Select

    For i = 1 To 40



    Cells(80, i + 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.MMult(Application.WorksheetFunction.MMult(Range(Cells(124 + i, 2).Address & ":" & Cells(124 + i, 1 + i).Address), Range(Cells(83, 2).Address & ":" & Cells(83 + i, 1 + i).Address)), Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range(Cells(124 + i, 2).Address & ":" & Cells(124 + i, 1 + i).Address)))



    Next



End Sub
```

Comment: I am not sure why it could not work, but I have since rectified the issue using the follow code:

Cells(80, i + 1).FormulaArray = "=SQRT(MMult(MMult(" & Cells(124 + i, 2).Address & ":" & Cells(124 + i, 1 + i).Address & "," & Cells(84, 2).Address & ":" & Cells(83 + i, 1 + i).Address & "), Transpose(" & Cells(124 + i, 2).Address & ":" & Cells(124 + i, 1 + i).Address & ")))"

This makes the cell referencing dynamic, but the rest is pretty much the application of the powerful matrix multiplication code that excel has. Most importantly, this requires the array formula and not just formula.